# warning:[unchecked] unchecked conversion

Tags: java

I am getting following warning :

```
warning:[unchecked] unchecked conversion
[javac]found:java.util.List
[javac] required:java.util.List<edu.fullerton.cs476s09.espressobar.jpa.espressobar_milk>
return query.getResultList();
```

What may be the problem and probable solution?
I am using following code:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(Order.class)
//@EntityListeners(MyListener.class)
public class OrderBean implements Order
{ 
    /**
     * The entity manager object, injected by the container
     */

    @PersistenceContext
    
    private EntityManager manager;
    
    public List<espressobar_milk> listMilk() 
    {
        Query query = manager.createQuery("SELECT m FROM espressobar_milk m");
        return query.getResultList();
    }...
.....
..}
```

Answer (score 11):

I am using EJB 3.1 and I had the same problem. I found another solution:

```
TypedQuery<espressobar_milk> query = manager.createQuery("SELECT m FROM espressobar_milk m", espressobar_milk.class);         
return query.getResultList();
```

This solves the unchecked conversation warning (you don't need the @SuppressWarnings annotation anymore).

Answer (score 10):

Well, we don't have details of what `Query` is here, but presumably its `getResultList` method returns a raw `List`. Basically the compiler can't be sure that the list returned by `getResultList` will only contain instances of `espressobar_milk` (it's slightly more subtle than that, but we'll leave it there for now).

You could try to make it strongly typed, probably by changing the `Query` class, or you could annotate the method with

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```

if you're convinced it's correct but there's no way of achieving compile-time safety.

Comment: Note, I still received a warning when I annotated the method in Java 1.7. However, the warning was actually suppressed when I annotated the entire class.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are using [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/), which is currently implementing JPA 1.0 (Hopefully Hibernate will implement JPA 2.0 when it is released. ([Toplink](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/index.html) is currently the reference implementation of JPA 2.0)). Hibernate is not using any java 1.5 features and thus no generic collections are available.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the result of

```
return query.getResultList();
```

is `List` and not `List< E >`, as it is expected ( `List< espressobar_milk >` ). [ http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html ] That's the reason it is showing the warning. In any case, you can suppress this warning using:

```
@SuppressWarnings ( "unchecked" )
public List<espressobar_milk> listMilk() 
{
    Query query = manager.createQuery("SELECT m FROM espressobar_milk m");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unchecked conversion warnings typically result from Java's Type Erasure mechanism for Generics. The idea is that code that uses generics can cooperate with code that does not use generics (in fact, the generated code omits the generic type).

However,you also get this warning when you try to "tack on" genericity to a non generic list (since this is different than a class-based cast that would throw a ClassCastException). In this case, trying to tack on the milk type to what is a non-generic list return by getResultList produces the error.

Read the [Java Generics tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) for more info on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
@SuppressWarning ( "unchecked" )
```

should be:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
```